# Select a tree node does not work

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have an application in Extjs and I need to select a specific node to expand the tree.

I am using the following method:

```
var record = tree.getRootNode().FindChild('text', 'employee', true); 
tree.getSelectionModel().select(record);
```

in this way does not work, but if I select any one node and then run the above method, it works without problems.

Help please

UPDATE
CODE:

```
tree.expandPath(route, "text", "->", function() {
             var record = tree.getRootNode().findChild('text','BASE',true);
             tree.getSelectionModel().select(record);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends thanks for your help, I was able to solve my problem.

Apparently I did not select the node because it had not shown the window and the nodes were not available, so here add a listener after render.

so I stay my code:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender : function(){
          this.selectPath(this.ruta, 'text', '->', function (s,n) {
              var nodeEl = Ext.get(this.view.getNode(n));                                     
              nodeEl.scrollIntoView(this.view.el, false, true);
              });
    }
}
```

this solution apart from selecting me too the node moves to its location in the tree.

hopefully serve them.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the node is not loaded yet. If you need to expand the tree, the best way is to use [expandPath](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-method-expandPath) method and if you need to select the node then do it in expandPath callback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply 
I created a callback function, I just expands the node path, but not selected.

Comment: Is the node found? You can check it by adding `console.log(record)` after the "findChild" line.

Answer (score 0):

When do you try to select the node with this code? While the tree panel got generated? In this case, perhaps some code from treepanels implementation will reset the selection. So for testing try it with a lock on the the selectionModel:

```
var record = tree.getRootNode().findChild('text','BASE',true);
tree.getSelectionModel().select(record);
tree.getSelectionModel().setLocked(true);
```

(If you know already the node which should be expanded while loading data for the store, you can also set "expanded" to true in the data for this specific record/node. Then the expansion is done by ExtJS automatically.)